# TFS Release - get list of available releases for given environment

Tags: tfs, release

I'm trying to use TFS Release management on TFS 2017/2018 on prem.

I have releases created every time artifact is created. I also have several environments to deploy releases to. QA-1 environment is updated every time we have new artifact (can be several times a day). QA-2 environment should be updated once a day.

How can I get list of releases available for deployment to QA-2 environment?

If I had Release-20 already deployed overnight. During the day we created Release-21, 22, 23 (all deployed to QA-1). Is there a way to tell that 21, 22, 23 are available for QA-2 environment using API?

I tried this but it shows what was already deployed:

```
https://<server>/<project>/_apis/release/deployments?definitionId=12&definitionEnvironmentId=28
```

It does not show those that are not deployed yet (those that I'm looking for).

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Unless there is better way that I can't see at the moment, this may work.

Get latest deployed release to the environment.

```
https://<server>/<collection>/<project>/_apis/release/deployments?definitionId=<def_ID>&definitionEnvironmentId=<env_ID>&$top=1&api-version=4.1-preview.2
```

Get  when this release was created from JSON. Add one second to the  to be used in next command:

```
https://<server>/<collection>/<project>/_apis/release/releases?definitionId=<def_ID>&minCreatedTime=<datetime>&api-version=4.1-preview.2
```

Now we can iterate through releases in this JSON result.

Here is the powershell script to get the concept:

```
param(
    [String]$TFSurl         = "",               # URL to access TFS server
    [String]$TFScollection  = "",               # Collection name in TFS
    [String]$TFSproject     = "",               # Name of the project in TFS
    [String]$APIversion     = "4.1-preview.2",  # Version of API to be used

    [String]$definitionId               = "",   # Release definition ID
    [String]$definitionEnvironmentId    = "",   # Environment ID inside the release definition


    $debugTrace = "SilentlyContinue" # SilentlyContinue, Continue
)

$dtformat = 'yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.FFFFFK'    # DateTime format used by TFS API and returned in Json.


# Get last release that was deployed to the environment to get date and time when it was created
$uri = "$TFSurl/$TFScollection/$TFSproject/_apis/release/deployments?definitionId=$definitionId&definitionEnvironmentId=$definitionEnvironmentId&`$top=1&api-version=$APIversion"

Write-Host "Calling REST: $uri"
$result = Invoke-RestMethod -Method 'Get' -ContentType 'application/json' -uri $uri -UseDefaultCredentials

Write-Host "Release Definition:    " $result.value.releaseDefinition.name
Write-Host "Environment name:      " $result.value.releaseEnvironment.name
Write-Host "Last release deployed: " $result.value.release.name
Write-Host "Release create date:   " $result.value.completedOn

# add 1 second to create date to make sure we don't get the same realease again
$dateTimeNew=[datetime]::ParseExact($result.value.completedOn,$dtformat,$Null).AddSeconds(1).ToString($dtformat)
Write-Host "Release time +1 second:" $dateTimeNew

# Get list of releases avaialble since specified date and time
$uri = "$TFSurl/$TFScollection/$TFSproject/_apis/release/releases?definitionId=$definitionId&minCreatedTime=$dateTimeNew&queryOrder=ascending&api-version=$APIversion"

Write-Host "Calling REST: $uri"
$result = Invoke-RestMethod -Method 'Get' -ContentType 'application/json' -uri $uri -UseDefaultCredentials

foreach ($V in $result.value) {
    Write-Host "Release: $($V.releaseDefinition.name) (id=$($V.releaseDefinition.id)) $($V.name) (id=$($V.id))"
}
```